# Dart2 Router Implementation

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I am trying to upgrade Dart1 application to Dart 2.4, I am facing a problem in Router my code is as shown below

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:angular/src/core/di/decorators.dart';
@Injectable()
class SpRouterImpl implements SpRouter {
 final Router _router;

 SpRouterImpl(this._router);
 @override
 void go(String routeName, Map<String, String> parameters,
  [bool openInNewWindow = false]) {
  if (openInNewWindow) {
  var url = _router.generate([routeName, parameters]).component.urlPath;
  window.open(url, "_blank");
 } else {
  _router.navigate([routeName, parameters]);
 }
}
}
```

I am getting error in this line

```
var url = _router.generate([routeName, parameters]).component.urlPath;
```

The method generate isn't defined for the class Router

Second error is here

```
_router.navigate([routeName, parameters]);
```

The argument type List can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

The above function is working fine in Dart 1 but when I upgrade to Dart 2, I am getting the errors, don't know how to solve it.

Can anyone help in this regard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `RoutePath` instance to define your "route".

```
final search = RoutePath(path: "search/:term"); // term is the parameter
```

Then use that path to navigate to that route.

```
_router.navigate(search.toUrl(parameters: {'term': searchTerm}));
```

So in your case it might look like this:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:angular/src/core/di/decorators.dart';
@Injectable()
class SpRouterImpl implements SpRouter {
   final Router _router;

   SpRouterImpl(this._router);
   @override
   void go(String routeName, Map<String, String> parameters,
    [bool openInNewWindow = false]) {
     final path = RoutePath(routeName);
     final url = path.toUrl(parameters: parameters)
     if (openInNewWindow) {
       window.open(url, "_blank");
     } else {
       _router.navigate(url);
     }
   }
}
```

It might not drop in and work depending on how your `routeName` is defined but this is the general idea.

There are several other options for [RoutePath](https://angulardart.dev/api/angular_router/angular_router/RoutePath-class) check them out and see what works best for you!